# Enabling Login Failure Audit in MS Dynamics 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm

My company has a requirement to log both the failed and successful logins to applications.

For ms dynamics 2015, I know that there are logs on when a user is signed on, but I haven't managed to find the failed login logs

Comment: This depends on the authentication method you are using - if you use Active Directory Federation Service (ADFS) and Claim-based authentication, failed login attempts may not reach Dynamics CRM ^because they already get rejected by ADFS.

Comment: For our setup the login is via Active Directory. So we should be looking at logs from Active Directory?